# Объекты в руке проваливаются через меши в Godot

Tags: godot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Главный герой моей игры держит в руке гаечный ключ и когда игрок подходит к стене, логично, что гаечный ключ проваливается через стену. В смысле уходит за неё. В Unity эта проблема решалась созданием двух камер и добавлением разных слоёв и т.д., а в Godot я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Я не спец в godot, но по-моему тут нужно просто изменить размер/форму коллайдера. Добавление слоёв и камер это извращение.

Comment: нет, ты неправильно понял. я имел в виду, что игрок держит в руке предмет. и когда игрок подходит к стенк, часть предмета не видна, т.к. предмет немного зашёл за стену. но я хочу, чтобы предмет был виден даже если он зашёл за стену. есть в материалах флаг "no depth test", но он не подходит, т.к. из-за этого текстура неправильно отображается

Comment: я обновил пост, посмотри

Comment: Почему я не правильно понял? Я всё так и понял. Если бы коллайдер персонажа был шире, он просто не мог бы подойти к стене настолько близко, чтобы меч в ней тонул.

Comment: каппец гениально

Comment: Ну да, это самое простое решение. Если вам нужен реализм, можно прицепить отдельный коллайдер на этот гаечный ключ, но чем больше физических объектов в сцене, тем ниже производительность.